# problem with storing data in datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

I am facing a problem with file upload.I have used Apache Commons
servlet file upload for uploading the file. Though the file is getting
uploaded and the data is getting stored on the local server(http://
127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/admin/datastore) but it is not going to the Google
App Engine datastore. 
What I am doing is loading
the file as a stream and immediately parsing the stream and creating
datastore entities with the data. I am not actually trying to save the
file. In the local server it works. It even works when I try to access
the local server from another machine. However it does not work when I
deploy it to Appengine using the Google Pluggin for Eclipse. My parsing
code depends on resource files which are under the web-inf  directory.
Is it possible these resource files are not getting uploaded and is
there a way to check what files are uploaded on Appengine?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever's in your `.war` is going up into AppEngine. I don't see how parts of it will be selectively excluded. What's more likely is that your application is depending on stuff that is lurking SOMEwhere on your PC but not included in that .war file.

However, shouldn't your application be checking for those resources and throwing exceptions if they are not found? If it's failing silently, I'd consider that a design flaw.

Logging a lot may help you debug the problem. You can look at your program's logs via the AppEngine console. I recommend more error checking and logging.

Something else to check for is to not be running the version of your software you think you are. There's a kind of versioning mechanism that allows you to deploy different concurrent versions of your and only one will be actually accessible. One of the things you should be logging and/or making otherwise accessible is some version information (perhaps even including a build timestamp) for your app's build.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did try logging my app with following:

if (item.isFormField()) {
 log.warning("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName());
} else {
 log.warning("Got an uploaded file: " + item.getFieldName() +
                               ", name = " + item.getName());
int len;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((len = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                     log.info(buffer.toString());}

though it gave correct value for 1st log statement, it gave garbage values for 2nd one irrespective of my file type.
Can you explain this?

Comment: If by "the second one" you meant logging `buffer.toString()`, that's understandable. The String representation of an array is "L" and some address. You might want to try Arrays.toString(buffer) instead.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is showing some ASCII values for the data in the file. Does this mean atleast my file is getting uploaded? If yes then why is the data not reaching the google-datastore?

Comment: Well, if you're not checking len then you can't even be sure of that. But probably yes. Why don't you try accessing the value you stuck into the store immediately afterwards and see what's there?

Comment: Act I dont want to get into the file. I just want to upload a kml file and unmarshall it using the java api for kml and store contents into datastore. M directly using Kml.unmarshall(InputStream stream).

Answer (score 0):

The files in the .war folder are executed in the app engine and the others are uploaded. What you need to verify is the path you have set and the path of you source java file and the file you are reading. You cannot use the local file system path in app engine. You need to include the file in your project